# Proof that the localization $R_S$ is naturally isomorphic to the localization at the saturation $R_{\overline{S}}$?

Tags: ring-theory, category-theory

Localizations have the universal property that if $S$ is a multiplicative subset of a commutative ring $R$, and $i\colon S\to R$ is the canonical embedding, then if $g\colon R\to T$ is any map such that $g(s)$ is a unit in $T$ for all $s$, then there exists a unique homomorphism $h\colon R_S\to T$ such that $g=hf$.

I was reading a [handout](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/210BPage/handouts/math210b-localization.pdf) of Brian Conrad's that said that the localizing at $S$ is the same as localizing at the saturation $\overline{S}$ of $S$, as can be seen "instantly" by the universal property, since the universal property of $R_S$ implies that this ring also has the universal property to be the localization with respect to $\overline{S}$.

How can you use the universal property to see this instantly? Taking $f: R\to R_S$ and $\bar{f}:R\to R_\overline{S}$ to be the standard embeddings, and $g:R\to R_\overline{S}:r\mapsto rs/s$ and $\bar{g}:R\to R_S:r\mapsto r\bar{s}/\bar{s}$ to essentially also be standard embeddings, so that they send elements of $S$ and $\overline{S}$ to units, I found unique $h$ and $\bar{h}$ such that $g=hf$ and $\bar{g}=\bar{h}\bar{f}$ in hopes that $h$ and $\bar{h}$ would be isomorphisms between $R_S$ and $R_\overline{S}$, but it doens't seem to be working.

Comment: Anyone interested in the one-line-proof with the Yoneda Lemma?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I'm sorry, I never saw your comment. I would like to see it if you post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\bar f$ maps the elements of $S$ to invertible elements, it factorizes uniquely through $f$ by the universal property of the latter. On the other hand, since every element of $\bar S$ is mapped by $f$ to an invertible element of $R_S$, $f$ factors uniquely through $\bar f$.

You can check that the two compositions of the maps which establish these factorings are identities, using again the universal properties.

Comment: Thanks Mariano. So I know there exist unique maps $h$ and $\bar{h}$ such that $\bar{f}=hf$ and $f=\bar{h}\bar{f}$. How do you use universal properties to show they are isomorphisms? I played around and found $\bar{f}=h\bar{h}\bar{f}$ and $f=\bar{h}hf$.

Comment: Well, if $f=\bar h h f$ then $\bar hh$ must be the identity.

Comment: Why doesn't it only imply that $\bar{h}h$ is the identity on the image of $f$?

Comment: $f:R\to R_S$ is a map which maps the elements of $S$ to invertible elements, so there exists exactly one morphism $u:R_S\to R_S$ such that $f=uf$. But $u=\mathrm{id}$ works and $\bar hh$ also works, so...

Comment: Oh I see now. You apply the property to $f$ itself to get that unique $u$...sorry, thanks.

Comment: Don't be sorry!

Comment: All those people who still think that it's a good idea to repeat the Yoneda Lemma in 100 special cases instead of proving it in the lectures should be sorry.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, I am of the opposite opinion. One should only learn the abstract-nonsensy version of things at the point where one can, in all honstly, say «duh». Category theory should only be learned when one already knows it.

Comment: (I know too many people you can talk on cue for 30 minutes about generalities for which they cannot name an example... Mr. Miyagi would have made a great algebra professor)

Answer (score 4):

As Brian writes in his handout, use the universal property: on the one hand, $\overline{S}$ has invertible image in $R_S$, by definition.

Now given any morphism $R \to R'$ for which the elements of $\overline{S}$ become
 invertible in $R'$,
we see in particular that the elements of $S$ become invertible in $R'$.  Thus (by the universal property) we get a uniquely determined morphism $R_S \to R'$.

Thus $R_S$ satisfies the same universal property as $R_{\overline{S}}$, and so
they are canonically isomorphic.

(Note that Mariano's proof is just a proof of this canonical isomorphism adapted to the case at hand.)