# When are two localisations the same?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, localization

Consider $S$, the localisation of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ at the multiplicative set $\{ 1, x^3, x^6, \ldots \}$. Now, $x^2/x^3$ is an element of $S$, and it seems to me that this behaves the same as $1/x$. Therefore, it seems we get the same result as if we had localised at $\{ 1,x,x^2,x^3,\ldots \}$ instead.

Am I correct that these two localisations are "the same"? If so, given a ring $R$, and multiplicative subsets $M, N \subseteq R$, when are $\mathrm{Loc}(R,M)$ and $\mathrm{Loc}(R,N)$ "the same" / canonically isomorphic?

Comment: Yes, the two localizations are the same, and your logic is fine. The answer to the question "when is $R\to S^{-1}R$ isomorphic to $R\to T^{-1}R$" is exactly when the saturations of $S$ and $T$ are equal: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/636531/proof-that-the-localization-r-s-is-naturally-isomorphic-to-the-localization-at). I think this question may be an abstract duplicate of the linked one - do you agree, or would you like me to flesh this comment out  as an answer?

Comment: @KReiser: it's similar but not an exact duplicate. I'm not sure what the saturation of $S$ is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, these two localizations are the same, and your logic is completely fine.

To answer your larger question, we define the *saturation* $\hat{S}$ of a multiplicatively closed subset $S\subset R$ to be the set of elements $r\in R$ so that there exists an $r'\in R$ so that $rr'\in S$.
It's not so difficult to see that $S^{-1}R$ is isomorphic to $\hat{S}^{-1}R$ as an $R$-algebra: clearly $R\to \hat{S}^{-1}R$ factors uniquely through $R\to S^{-1}R$ since every element in $S$ is invertible in $\hat{S}^{-1}R$; conversely, every element in $\hat{S}$ is invertible in $S^{-1}R$ as $r\cdot r'/(rr')=1$ so $R\to S^{-1}R$ factors uniquely through $R\to \hat{S}^{-1}R$.

This establishes that $S^{-1}R$ is always isomorphic as an $R$-algebra to $\hat{S}^{-1}R$, so if $S,T$ are two multiplicatively closed subsets having the same saturation, then $S^{-1}R\cong T^{-1}R$ as a $R$-algebras. Conversely, if $S$ and $T$ are two multiplicatively closed subsets with different saturations, then $S^{-1}R$ and $T^{-1}R$ are not isomorphic as $R$-algebras with their standard $R$-algebra structures: we might as well assume that $S$ and $T$ are saturated and that there's some element $s\in S$ not in $T$, and then $s$ has invertible image in $S^{-1}R$ but not $T^{-1}R$.

Comment: Does $r'$ come from $S$ or $R$?

Comment: $r'\in R$, and I've edited that in.

Comment: KReiser Why if saturations are different  ie if $ \bar{S} \neq \bar{T}$ then $S^{-1} A$ and $T^{-1}A$ are never isomorphic? Can you please explain in detail

Comment: @James that's not what I wrote. Please read the post more carefully: if the two sets have different saturations, then the two localizations are not isomorphic as $A$ algebras with their standard structures, because there's an element of $A$ which is a unit in one but not the other.

Comment: @KReiser In second paragraph of your answer what do you mean by "factors through" ie $R\to \hat{S}^{-1}R$ factors uniquely through $R\to S^{-1}R$?

Comment: @Avenger [did you search?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57404/meaning-of-a-mapping-factors-over-another)